Time loop movie where the loop is shrinking
I've seen the movie about ten years ago; so around 2014.
Somehow, a time loop has started, maybe due to an experiment.
The bad guy is a military official.
The time loop shortens as the movie progresses.
There is a nuclear device involved near the end of the movie.
The time loop becomes very short at the end.

 The bad guy tries to disable the nuclear device and it detonates in his face. The time loop shrinks to about 1 second and the nuclear device detonates in his face repeatedly for all eternity.


Hi. I tried improving your title to make it more descriptive and less generic.

This is "Déjà Vu" (1999), S5.E16 of The Outer Limits (1995–2002).
From The Outer Limits Wiki:

A teleportation experiment goes wrong and the wormhole it created expands and engulfs the scientists. Suddenly, they're back to the day before, but only one man seems to remember what happened.

The protagonist, Dr. Mark Crest, is a scientist in charge of a teleportation experiment being overseen by his friend, Colonel Lester Glade.
The experiment resembles a nuclear weapons test, with the teleportation device located in a field, the people conducting the test in a building a few miles away, a countdown timer on the wall, and the device needing to be 'armed.' The plan is to open a wormhole that will teleport some animals in cages next to the device into cages within the building where the scientists are. The Colonel mentions that the test requires the energy of a tactical nuclear warhead.
The test is initiated but something goes wrong. The animals disappear but don't reappear and the teleportation field expands to cover a much wider area than it's supposed to, including the building where the scientists are. At the instant he's caught within the field, Crest yanks out some cables in an attempt to cut power to the device and is electrocuted. He then finds that time has regressed by 18 hours and he's the only one who remembers what happened.
After more or less the same thing happens again, he realises he's in a time loop and that the loops are getting shorter each time (i.e. time is regressing by shorter intervals). It subsequently comes to light that the Colonel has modified the device with the goal of turning it into a temporal displacement bomb that can be used to wink opposing military forces out of existence.
Crest drives out to the device to try to undo the modifications with just minutes left on the timer, but is interrupted by the Colonel, who shoots him in the shoulder. However, Crest did enough to reduce the radius of the teleportation field, so only the Colonel is caught within it when the device goes off this time, causing him to disappear.
Time stops looping for Crest and everyone else, while the Colonel is stuck in an infinite loop outside the normal flow of time, reliving the moment the device went off and engulfed him over and over again.




that looks like what I remember ... thanks

Is this Source Code (2011)…?
You can find a synopsis from IMDB below:

A man (Jake Gyllenhaal) wakes up on a train sitting across from a woman named Christina Warren (Michelle Monaghan). The woman knows him by the name Sean Fentress, but he doesn't seem to know her and appears uncertain of his own identity. After eight minutes, a bomb goes off on the train, and the man awakens to find himself strapped inside a small geodesic dome. There, Air Force Capt. Colleen Goodwin (Vera Farmiga) explains to him through a computer screen that he is actually Colter Stevens, a decorated army helicopter pilot, now on a mission to locate the maker of a bomb which destroyed a train headed into Chicago. This is to be accomplished using the Source Code, a time loop program that allows him to take over someone's body in a reenactment of their last eight minutes of life.


thanks for the answer ... it does not quite match what I remember ... I'll watch the movie end to confirm

It mostly matches except for the "time loop getting shorter" part. The time loop in Source Code remains the same length through.

The details you provided remind me of the Doctor Who serial "The Armageddon Factor", which was the sixth and final serial of season 16. Below is an excerpt from the serial's Wikipedia article:

The planet Atrios, ruled by Princess Astra, is losing a nuclear war with their neighbouring planet Zeos. Astra, on a tour to rally the injured troops within their safety bunker, is beguiled into seeking safety in a false shelter. Soon after, while searching for the Key to Time's final segment, the Fourth Doctor and Romana arrive, encountering Astra before she is suddenly abducted. After some initial false accusations from the leading bull-headed military Marshal, the Doctor agrees to help his increasingly weak efforts against Zeos. The Doctor and Romana discover that there is another factor in the war, when Romana notices a control device attached to the Marshal's neck, the Doctor deduces there is another planetary object between Atrios and Zeos, and a skull-shaped receiver is found behind a mirror that the Marshal seemingly uses to meditate with.
The Doctor is abducted during an attempt to transmaterialise/transmat (teleport) to Zeos, and meets with the true opponent, the "Shadow", ruling over a space station called the "Planet of Evil". However, as part of the Shadow's stratagem, he releases the Doctor, hoping he will misstep in his search for the Segment. The Doctor transmats to Zeos, genuinely this time, reuniting with Romana, an Atrion officer, and K9. They all find that Zeos is deserted, its inhabitants possibly already annihilated, save for the giant supercomputer Mentalis, which is controlling the outcome of the war. K9 is able to communicate with it, and Mentalis declares the war over.
However, the Marshal seeks victory through his opponent's annihilation, and launches a single flagship offence to the planet. Mentalis detects the launch, and, unable to defend itself after surrendering, begins a self-destruct sequence set to destroy both Zeos and Atrios. The Doctor attempts to stop it, but it damages its central control after its perimeter defence is triggered. With a lack of options, the Doctor fashions an artificial stopgap Segment, and orders the Key to Time to shroud the Marshal's ship and Mentalis' systems in an imperfect deteriorating time loop.
Meanwhile, K9 is abducted by the Shadow and fitted with another control device. The Doctor's group reunites with Astra, seemingly escaped but actually made a pawn of the Shadow as well. With Astra's help, the Doctor pilots the TARDIS back to the Planet of Evil. There, they are all separated. The Doctor encounters another Time Lord, Drax, whom he last met at the Gallifreyan Academy. Drax, who is under duress, was employed by The Shadow to build Mentalis, but he agrees to help the Doctor, and also frees K9. The Shadow reveals he is an agent of the Black Guardian, and demands the Key to Time, threatening to torture Romana. The Doctor leads a servant of the Shadow, known as a Mute, to his TARDIS and opens the door, but Drax misinterprets the Doctor's plan, and shrinks the Doctor and himself, using a dimensional stabiliser from Drax's own TARDIS.
The Mute returns to the Shadow with the Key, and Romana realises why the Shadow needs it: Astra herself is the final segment, and from the Key's power, she transforms in front of everyone. The Doctor and Drax smuggle themselves into the Shadow's lair inside of K9, who pretends to be under the Shadow's control. Drax again uses the stabiliser to normalise themselves. In the confusion, The Doctor snatches the partially-assembled Key and the final segment, and escapes with Romana, Drax, and K9 into the TARDIS. They return to Zeos, and, with the false Key segment and the time loop both expired, narrowly deactivate Mentalis' self-destruct, but the Doctor also realises that the Marshal is still en route. He quickly erects a shield around Zeos with the TARDIS, to deflect the Marshal's missiles towards the Planet of Evil, destroying it and killing the Shadow.


thank you for the reply, but it wasn't Dr. Who
